# How to refresh Radio button on multipage jquerymobile

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova, multipage

Is there any example on refreshing the radio-buttons value, that exist on one page and their value is changed from other page.
I have tried the following but its not working. [ using phonegap+jquerymobile+HTML5 ]
The following is the jquerymobile syntax called by the main page while the radio buttons exist on page2:-

```
if (result.rows.item(0).pri==0)
      {

            $('#radio2').prop('checked', true);
     }
      else {

            $('input:radio[id=radio3]').prop('checked', true);

      }

        $("input[type='radio']").checkboxradio();
        $("input[type='radio']").checkboxradio("refresh");
```

getting the following error on eclipse Android development studio

**cannot call refresh before page initialization.**

any suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

you may need to regenerate the widgets (the form element) by .triger("create")

Detail please refer Enhancing new markup from http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-scripting.html